# Conversion question

Tags: c#

Can someone please tell me how to do this in C#?

Convert from Quoted Printable to binary, and then use UTF-8 encoding to decode that binary to text.

Here is example of text I need quoted:

"Commentaires: Je suis abonn=C3=A9 =C3=A0 la livraison =C3=A0 domicile depuis longtemps."

Comment: This homework ?  http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp  ;)

Comment: You need to specify your question fully. The terms you use are vague and ill-defined.

Comment: @Noldorin: The term “quoted-printable” is very well-defined indeed. Just because you don’t know what it means doesn’t mean it’s vague :) (Also, I’m amazed how many people confuse it with base-64, which is completely different)

Comment: @Timwi: 'Binary' is ambiguous. Examples and concreteness always help, and none was provided (until now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so your question is basically two questions in one. First, you need to be able to decode quoted-printable. I’m assuming that you have the encoded text as a string. You’ll have to run through this string with a while-loop, like below. I’ve deliberately left out the part where you turn the two hex characters into a byte; I’m sure you can figure this out for yourself :)

```
var i = 0;
var output = new List<byte>();
while (i < input.Length)
{
    if (input[i] == '=' && input[i+1] == '\r' && input[i+2] == '\n')
    {
        // skip this
        i += 3;
    }
    else if (input[i] == '=')
    {
        byte b = (construct the byte from the characters input[i+1] and input[i+2]);
        output.Add(b);
        i += 3;
    }
    else
    {
        output.Add((byte)input[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

At the end of this, `output` contains the raw bytes. Now all you need to do is decode it using UTF8:

```
var outputString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
```

If you have any questions, please ask in a comment. And remember: don’t copy and use code that you don’t understand :)

Comment: By the way, the code I posted will crash when given invalid input like `"=A"`. Can you figure out why, and how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I just don't get how to convert the equals C3 and equals A9 to the é character (latin small letter e with acute), nor the equals C3 and equals A0 to the à character (latin small letter a with grave).

Comment: You don’t have to. That’s what `Encoding.UTF8` does for you. All you have to do is convert the characters 'C' '3' into the byte 0xC3 (195) etc.